# I've a dataset contains all details about the employee and have to predict whether he is good or bad based on the other features

Tags: machine-learning-model

I've a dataset contains all details about the employee and have to  predict whether he is good or bad based on the other features, what is the suitable ML algorithm to predict this kind of target variable?

Comment: This is a binary classification problem. The specific approach to follow would very much depend on the type of features you have.

Comment: Thanks noe, the other features are like employee's task, task completed mins, employee's efficiency, employee's utilization and all; can I use random forest here or any other classification algorithms?

Comment: Again, it depends. Do you have a fixed number of tasks or is it variable? You'd better post some samples of your data to make it easier to define how to approach it.

Comment: Hi Noe, the Features and their data types will be like,                                               Column name      Data type
Customer type Str
Task type                 Str
Task request            Str
Planned duration Datetime
Customer rating Int
Employee's name Str                                                                                                     
The data set has only str, datetime and int data type columns only,